# Disable touch event for notification bar in Android

Tags: android, status, notification-bar

Is there a way to disable click on the notification bar when my activity is displayed?

Basically I want to lock the notification bar so that the user will not be able to interact with it.

Comment: Generally you don't get and shouldn't be trying to lock the user out of parts of built-in android functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Set this in your notification:

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                                                        null,
                                                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
```

Comment: Kalpana, this will work when we set our notification right? but i dont want to allow the user to pull the notification bar or interact with any of the notification bar items.

Answer (score -1):

You can make your activity to full screen. Add this to your activity tag in the manifest file:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: if it solves your purpose then you should accept the answer else it will float as unanswered question...

Comment: Actually i need to have the notification bar but at the same time user shouldn't be able to interact with it.